# Unity game Drag Object with finger movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and develop mobile 2d game,now I am able to make an object move right and left when I touch the screen before or after the screen center. But I want to touch the object and drag it on the x axis while my finger is still touching the screen and move,so I want the object to be in the same x position of my finger, 
Any One can help me how to do it correctly: 
here is the code of how I am moving the object if I touched before or after the screen center:

```
public class paddle : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed;
    public float maxX;
    bool currentisAndroid=false;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        currentisAndroid=true;
        #else
        currentisAndroid=false;
        #endif
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (currentisAndroid == true) {
            if (Input.GetTouch (0).position.x < Screen.width/2 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
                moveLeft ();
            else if (Input.GetTouch (0).position.x > Screen.width/2 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
                moveRight ();
            else
                stop ();

        } else {
            float x = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
            //if (Input.GetTouch (0).position.x == rb.position.x && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            if (x == 0)
                stop ();
            if (x < 0)
                moveLeft ();
            if (x > 0)
                moveRight ();

            Vector2 pos = transform.position;
            pos.x=Mathf.Clamp (pos.x,-maxX,maxX);
            transform.position = pos;
        }


    }
    void moveLeft()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (-speed, 0);
    }
    void moveRight()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (speed, 0);
    }
    void stop()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (0, 0);
    }
    public float getposition()
    {
        return rb.position.y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way:

Add component **DragRigidbody** script and you will be able to drag objects via mouse or touchScreen touches.

Answer (score 0):

If I Understand correctly: 
1 - Raycast from finger location vertically with your camera into the scene.
2 - select the hit object.
3 - map your camera to world coordinates and move that object according to hit point of your ray with map or game object\objects.

- Physics.Raycast();
- RaycastHit.collider();
- Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(<0 or 1 or all>).position);

If you want to move object across a map  you can track your touch and when its close to the corners move the camera on that direct (horizontal - vertical).